# Mapping type in cpp using template

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have a function template from an external library that needs user-defined type for using it.

```cpp
template < int runtime_t >
typename ExtLib::apply<runtime_t>::type get_value(std::string) ;
```

To use it, I need to specify the user-defined type like:

```cpp
get_value<ExtLib::pool_t::boolean_>("key_of_boolean_value");
get_value<ExtLib::pool_t::float_>("key_of_float_value");
```

I would like to wrap this "ExtLib" in order to hide it from the main program in such way I can use it with builtin cpp type:

```cpp
bool val = get_value<bool>("key");
float val2 = get_value<float>("key2");
```

I've tried using a map but without any success. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could make mapping from standard types to lib types via class templates:

```
template <typename T>
struct Convert;

template <>
struct Convert<bool>
{
   static const int value = ExtLib::pool_t::boolean;
};

template <>
struct Convert<float>
{
   static const int value = ExtLib::pool_t::float;
};

.. map other types
```

and then

```
template <typename T>
auto get_value(const std::string& key)
{
     return get_value<Convert<T>::value>(key)
}
```

Or you could define a function template `get_value` in your own namespace, and overload or specialize it to use the function with the same name from the library namespace, for ex.

```
// libadapter.h
namespace myns
{
    template <typename T>  T get_value(const string& key);

    // specialize for bool, for ex.
    template <bool>
    bool get_value(const std::string& key) 
    {
         return library::get_value<Extlib::pool_t::boolean>(key));
    }
     
     /* or 
     template <bool>
     auto get_value(const std::string& key)
     {
           return static_cast<bool>(library::get_value<Extlib::pool_t::boolean>(key))
     }
     */

      
    // specialize for float
    template <float>
    float get_value(const std::string& key)
    {
          return library::get_value<Extlib::pool_t::float>(key);
    }

    // ... specialize for other types as well, if necccessary ... 
}
```

then in some .cpp:

```
#include "libadapter.h"
using myns::get_value;
... use get_value ...
```

Comment: One suggestion though. Consider making the primary `template<class T> auto get_value(const string&);` and keep the `auto` in the specializations. One can't assume `std::is_same_v<typename ExtLib::apply<boolean_>::type, bool>` holds (although it's probably convertible to a `bool` since that's how OP uses it). Perhaps even make it `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: I've edited my question in order to make my point clearer. I would like to define my `get_value` function as a template using only cpp builtin types, but not only `bool`. I don't know the best way to pair cpp builtin types with user-defined types in order to be able to use a template function

Comment: @Ted Luyngmo: thanks, I think you're basically right. but here it seems that OP wants to be explicit about its return type. if I call `get_value<float>` and get some type other than float, than it would be rather surprising. if no implicit conversion is possible, than would rather prefere compiler warning or error

Comment: @Sigmun: you need to provide different specializations for each type you want to 'map' from library type to 'builtin' cpp type. have updated an example for float. you probably want to do this for other library types from `ExtLib::pool_t`

Comment: `auto` could be fine to me since I am able to call `ExtLib::get_value` with its corresponding user-defined type

Comment: u can use auto, but then probably `static_cast` for the type would be advisable. see update for boolean example

Comment: My point is to use template in order to specify types, not specialized declaration for each type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228258/discussion-between-sigmun-and-stpiere).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @StPiere, I could answer my own question with:

```cpp
std::undordered_map<std::type_index, int> map_types = {
{std::type_index(typeid(bool)), ExtLib::pool_t::boolean_},
{std::type_index(typeid(long)), ExtLib::pool_t::long_},
{std::type_index(typeid(float)), ExtLib::pool_t::float_},
{std::type_index(typeid(double)), ExtLib::pool_t::double_}
}

template <typename T>
T getValue(std::string key) {
const int TT = map_types[std::type_index(typeid(T))]
return get_value<TT>(key);
};
```

Comment: see also my updated answer for compile time option. using map you're still geting the mapped-to value at runtime